# Im using JqTouch, and when i reload a page which isn't homepage, ang go back, it goes to home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jqtouch

For example, I can have

---

#HOME - #Page1

#Page1 - #Page2

#Page2 - #Page3

---

If i'm on #Page3 and I reload the page, nothing changes. But if I click the back button, it goes to #HOME, but it's supposed to go back to #Page2.

The back button looks like this;

```
<a class="button back" href="#">Back</a>
```

Please tell me how to fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
<a class="button back" href="#Page2">Back</a>
```

Comment: Try this: `<a href="javascript:jQT.goTo('#Page2','slideleft')"></a>`